# add two rows to one text box ,is it possible

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is option to change textBox highet and put to it data in two rows
for example

```
Row1 - data for row 1....
Row2 data for row 2
```

Both of them in the same text box that row one is on top row two?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Would you be hiding one to show the other at some time?

Comment: I would use a textarea tag for this. `<textarea rows="2"></textarea>`

Comment: @aa333 no I want it to be disabled...

Comment: If you want the two rows to be different always even when 1st row is not overflown, then I suggest using `contenteditable` elements like div and then wrap them in single container div.

Comment: @schmidt382-can you please provide example how I put the row one on top row 2 in the text area?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to insert text into a textarea in two entries that correspond with two rows? Do you know the length of data for row 1 and data for row 2?

Comment: @schmidt382-yes the length of the first is 50px and second 70px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could insert the data into a textarea. With javascript (jquery), you can do this:

`var data1 = 'put your data1 value here';
var data2 = 'put your data2 value here';
$('textarea a selector here').val(data1 + '\n' + data2);`

Just make sure the textarea has enough columns to handle the longest data variable being inserted and they will stay on one line each.